# run a command in subfolders

Tags: linux, awk

I have a command `rdseed -d -R -p -f filename` which gives an output of response time and etc for each file in a subfolder. The problem is I want to run this command in all subfolders and the output (response time, pz) must be inside the subfolders. I've tried  using `ls -1 */*.file type | awk -F '[/]' '{print "rdseed -d -R -p -f "}'` but the result is just it do this in the file in the first subfolder and its was also placed in the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
IFS="\n" # Handle directories with spaces
for directory in $(find /path/to/location -type d); do
    rdseed -d -R -p -f "${directory}/filename"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague, but this might be what you want to do:

```
find $DIR -type f | xargs -n 1 rdseed -d -R -p -f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find "$DIR" -type f -name '*.file' -execdir rdseed -d -R -p -f {} \;
```

This finds all filenames matching `*.file` in `$DIR`, and runs `rdseed` (with the matching filename as the final arg) **in the directory** that each file was found in.

`rdseed` is run once for each filename found.